# disable apt-listchanges (and other interactive stuff) during upgrades (reliably)

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have to admit, I really *really* hate apt-listchanges. If I'm going to do a huge dist-upgrade, I want to just leave the computer there for a few hours. The asker of this [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/48724/100-non-interactive-debian-dist-upgrade) had a similar goal in mind, bu after implementing all of the suggestions in that post, I was still hit by `apt-listchanges`.

Why is it so difficult to achieve non-interactivity with `apt`, an otherwise excellent program, given that the Unix philosophy aspires to it?

I am hoping the changes I made to `/etc/apt/listchanges.conf` will help, but I want suggestions as to how to reliably do upgrades without any interaction whatsoever.

```
[apt]
frontend=none
email_address=root
confirm=0
save_seen=/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db
which=news
```

This is the command I used was

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
apt-get \
-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" \
--force-yes \
-fuy \
dist-upgrade
```

I also added the following lines to `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg`

```
force-confold
force-confdef
```

Comment: If you don't like `apt-listchanges`, why do you install it?

Comment: Aren't removing it with `apt-get purge apt-listchanges` helping you ?

Comment: Warl0ck's right. Uninstall it. I use apt-get non-interacctively all the time.

Comment: it came pre-installed with my latest debian... d'oh!

Comment: Yeah I really hate that this seems to be default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you found and set in your config, `apt-listchanges` should not prompt if you set the frontend to `none`.  You can also set the environment variable `APT_LISTCHANGES_FRONTEND=none` to achieve the same thing.

It sounds like what you really want to do is use the `unattended-upgrades` package.  It handles everything for you: disabling `apt-listchanges`, setting the frontend to `noninteractive`, checking for and avoiding conffile prompts, etc.  If nothing else, the contents of the Python script `/usr/bin/unattended-upgrades` should answer your questions about how it does its magic.

Comment: How does it avoid conffile prompts? Does it just ignore them by keeping your config or replacing it?

Comment: If your `apt` config contains `--force-confold` or `--force-confnew` in `DPkg::Options`, they behave as expected.  Otherwise, a package that would trigger a conffile prompt is not upgraded, and an email is sent (if email is configured in `unattended-upgrades`).  If email is not available, it's logged under `/var/log/unattended-upgrades`.