# All Debian package managers broken due to Python bug

Tags: debian, apt, python

I am trying to fix my **apt** to make it useable. It only ables to update the package list. I cannot remove or install any package. The error I am getting is

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f1031850700 (most recent call first):
Aborted
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10
```

I tried setting the `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` in `/etc/environment`. Following is my `environment` file.

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
PYTHONHOME="/usr/lib/python3.5"
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.5"
```

Is there a way to reinstall Python and pip without using Python dependant package managers? I think I am missing some library files but even Python2.7 doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307467/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47972/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448226/ .

Comment: And [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184504/86440) in particular seems very relevant. (I’m not suggesting a duplicate since I have a double hammer here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error isn’t caused by `apt` itself, but by `apt-listchanges`; disabling that will avoid the problem (`apt` isn’t Python-based):

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges{,.bak}
```

This won’t fix your Python problems, so you might run into other errors. You shouldn’t need to set `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` in `/etc/environment`, I recommend removing those lines too.

Once everything is fixed, you can enable `apt-listchanges` by running

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges{.bak,}
```

Comment: I am getting the error `E: python3-openrazer: subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 134` when trying to remove the troublsome packages.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/506646/edit) to show the complete output.

Comment: This happens after I disable the `apt-listchanges`. I have downloaded and manually installed both python 2.7 and python 3.5

Comment: What do you mean by “manually installed”? Again, please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/506646/edit) to include as much detail as possible.

Comment: I reinstalled Debian because i couldn't fix the issue.